# Using GNU autotools process and Oracle Pro C preprocessor

Tags: oracle, autotools, automake, oracle-pro-c

I am converting a few libs to GNU autotools and having a hard time to integrade Oracle Pro C preprocessor.

The workflow is as follows:
`.pc => .c => o. => .so/.a/binary`

I wasn't able to find any hints in the automake manual how to add an additional pre-steps to the build process.
I have tried to modify `SOURCES=file.pc` but autoreconf complains about missing C files. I have added `SUFFIXES = .pc .c .o` and

```
.pc.c:
      $(PROC) iname=$<
```

But the target is ignored -- and if called directly `$<` is never resolved.

What to do?

Comment: What `make` program is being used?  Is it GNU make or some other make?

Comment: @ldav1s, I have both at hand. I tried to put that into the `Makefile.am`. Does the `make` version make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
%.c : %.pc
        $(PROC) iname=$<

foo.o : foo.pc
```

seems to work for GNU make.  I don't have any other kind of make to test with.  IIRC, I think

```
.SUFFIXES : .pc
.pc.c:
        $(PROC) iname=$<
```

could work, but I don't have another `make` to test this out.

I tried this out and it did behave kind of like how you want.

```
foo_SOURCES= $(top_srcdir)/src/main.c $(top_srcdir)/src/foo.pc

SUFFIXES : .pc
.pc.c:
        $(PROC) iname=$<
```

Comment: The second one does definitively **not** work because automake does not accept that! I tried the first already but not to that extend. The issue is how do I tell automake that the generated Makefile should first run Pro C and then `cc`.